# Android: Anyway to know if 'Unknown Sources' is checked?

Tags: android, application-settings

Is there any way to find out if the user has checked the 'Unknown Sources' checkbox in the 'Application settings' menu?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to check if “Install from unknown source” is enabled on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6664984/456814).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS) setting. Something like that :

```
boolean canInstallFromOtherSources = Settings.Secure.getInt(Settings.Secure.INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS) == 1;
```